# Unable to ssh to gcloud VM instance from google/cloud-sdk:alpine docker container

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to connect to a google cloud VM instance from a GitLab CI/CD runner to be able to deploy docker swarm stacks and services. However I find that when running

```
gcloud compute ssh <instance-name> --quiet
```

from the google/cloud-sdk:alpine docker image the keys are uploaded to the image (as confirmed using the cloud console), however the connection fails with

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

When examining the output using -vvv, the last few lines of the output show

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/google_compute_engine
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:pbWpf3dF2nJgcR9Z7pPmIwTsS0IEKK5bgakYJfAQK5o
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:pbWpf3dF2nJgcR9Z7pPmIwTsS0IEKK5bgakYJfAQK5o
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Connecting using the SSH button in the cloud console works fine.

Any ideas as to what might be stopping this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of experimenting it turns out that signing in as a different user to root works, i.e. use

```
gcloud compute ssh <user-name>@<instance-name> --quiet
```

and this works fine. I assume that google don't allow root ssh access to their instances.